# Definition of Superfluid with no Bose-Einstein condensation?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

A BEC with no superfluidity is referred to as *Bose Glass* (due to S. Yukalov to my knowledge). Is anyone aware of a similar definition for systems which exhibit superfluid behaviour but are not Bose-Einstein condensed?

Comment: I believe this question is equivalent to this one https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31003/

Comment: The dark matter?

Comment: @user157879 no, it's a different question although related...

Comment: @semola Read the first answer, it addresses both BEC without superfluidity and superfluidity without BEC.

Comment: @user157879 I read that answer as well as the book cited there. My question is not on the difference between superfluids and BEC but on the nomenclature (if there is one at all) for a superfluid which is not condensed, e.g. a superfluid in 1D, or a 2D Kosterlitz-Thouless superfluid.