# Does it make sense to quantize perfect fluid?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fluid-dynamics, quantization

Wikipedia (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_fluid)) says perfect fluid may be quantized. I do find an article ([arXiv 1011.6396](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6396)) about this, and the procedure is straight forward. What I do not understand is whether this quantization really makes sense, i.e. whether the quantized liquid dynamics corresponds to actual systems.

For example, can a quantum many-body system - like electrons in a metal - be described using a quantized version fluid dynamics? Does this give a universal scheme of bosonization?

Answer (score 1):

[Liquid helium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate#Superfluid_helium-4) can be described as [superfluid](https://physicsworld.com/a/liquid-hydrogen-turns-superfluid/).

> the first liquid in which superfluidity was recognized was helium-4 back in 1938. It loses its viscosity below 2.12  K. At the time Fritz London suggested that the phenomenon was associated with Bose-Einstein condensation (BEC), which occurs when an assembly of bosons (particles with zero or integer “spin”) is cooled below a critical temperature. In Bose-Einstein condensation a large fraction of all the particles in the assembly congregate in the zero-momentum ground state.

....

> Although it is generally agreed that there is a close association between Bose-Einstein condensation and superfluidity, the exact relationship has yet to be established.

The review starts with"

> Recent work at Göttingen has revealed convincing evidence for superfluidity in liquid hydrogen, the only liquid other than helium to exhibit this quantum behaviour.

and ends with:

> How does this result relate to more conventional types of experiment? It should be emphasized that superfluidity in a shell containing about 15 hydrogen molecules does not necessarily mean that the phenomenon will ever be observed in bulk liquid. Indeed, it probably will not, due to the difficulty of maintaining the liquid state at low enough temperatures. .....

So it seems there is research going on.

Comment: I know superfluid, and actually I've read the fluid dynamics description of superfluids in Landau's fluid mechanics. Still, these sections in the book are about classical fluid mechanics instead of quantum ones, so that doesn't answer my question about the motivation to *quantize* fluid dynamics. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @jywu  relevant question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/31003/are-all-bose-einstein-condensates-superfluid